# adb devices -l not showing USB qualifiers?

Tags: adb, usb, command-line

I've read in several places that calling

> adb devices -l

will return the both the serial numbers and USB qualifiers for the attached devices. However, when I issue the command I only get the serial number and product information about the device. What can I do? This is important to me because I'm trying to target two of the same phone, which both have the same default serial number (0123456789ABCDEF).
[image]

Comment: I think it's more limited on Windows, but will getting the port info actually help?  AFAIK you can only specify the already connected device (with `-d`) or a serial number.

Comment: That's what I thought too, until I read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29966699/2953069

Comment: Interesting.  I'd suggest trying to change the serial numbers -- I found [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30252676/507761) that might work if they are rooted.